# Pasting Spreadsheet from Excel to Outlook, chart gets distorted

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-outlook-2010, charts

I have been able to copy a full workbook in the past and simply paste it into outlook to send the data set that I need to send. I recently updated the data set and included more data and now when I send the data the copied portion in outlook breaks the image. I have a picture of the problem attached, the bar chart should have another 15/20 items listed in it that are getting cut off. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Is there a difference if you use Format Text as Rich Text vs HTML? I'm not seeing this problem in Excel 2013 and Outlook 2013. Everything is copying over OK.

Answer (score 0):

I always post excel charts as images into other program to prevent any distortion or changing of colours or anything else microsoft decides to change.

Answer (score 0):

If you're concerned about the presentation of the workbook, I would print a `PDF` and then send it as an attachment. Screenshots of a figure are generally a decent way to accomplish this as well (use the <kbd>PrScrn</kbd> and then paste into MsPaint to crop/edit if desired).

If you want to send the dataset, `Export` it as a `CSV` (or other data format) and attach it, too.

In Office2016, both can be accomplished by selecting `File->Export` (File in the ribbon, Export in the popup sidebar). Use the "Change File Type" to select which you want.